# Google Sheet Script Sorting

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script

i'm trying to sort a specific range in google sheets which can always expand starting at column A and row 4 until the last column and row.

But that doesn't really work. Can i get the letter of a column number or is the another range function?

```
function sort() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = spreadsheet.getLastColumn();
  spreadsheet.getRange("A4:" & lastCol & lastRow).sort(1);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
function sort() {
  var sh= SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange(4,1,sh.getLastRow() - 3,sh.getLastColumn()).sort(1);
};
```